# How do I measure the volume of strictness of a json schema?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I have a json file and a schema for it. The file is valid but only when I make the json "less strong". For example, when I use `"oneOf": [...` it's invalid, likewise when I use `"anyOf": [...` it's valid but `"anyOf"` itself allows more "possibilities", makes it not that strict.

I want it to be as strict as possible. I hope you understand what I mean by strictness here. How do I measure the amount of strictness?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make a principled assesment of restrictness of schema, even if we just consider "oneOf" vs "anyOf".

Let's see the two following examples. They are pretty forced examples, but you could come up with many not so contrived.

{
  "anyOf": [
    { "type": "string", "maxLength": 5 },
    { "type": "string", "minLength": 5 }
  ]
}

{
  "oneOf": [
    { "type": "string", "maxLength": 5 },
    { "type": "string", "minLength": 5 }
  ]
}

From a mathematical point of view, the restrictness of a schema depends on the universe of samples that you want o model. So you can't say that a model is more accurate that other unless you relate it to the universe of samples.

So I would suggest you to take an empiric/test driven  approach to assess the accuracy of your model. 
You could build a collection of valid and invalid json samples, and create a list of json-schema candidates. 
You then choose the json-schema that maximize the number of invalid json samples while validating all the valid samples.